# google sheets sparkline column type byrow with Ymin & Ymax columns byrow too

Tags: google-sheets, sparklines

Recently I found a method really useful to have an "arrayformula" for the sparkline function.
As you can see in the [sparkline byrow](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J13TXVjPn81bYSexQsrqL7AYUQu81nN3xQJ0QYVGgYI/edit?usp=sharing) file in the I2 cell there is the only formula but I'm not able to find a good method to use dynamically min and max value.
Pratically I would like substitute the fix value "ymin"\0;"ymax"\400 with the values calculated in columns G and H row by row.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulas used to calculate the min and the max are `MIN(row)` and `MAX(row)*1,2` respectively. So you can use that instead of 0 and 400 in your `BYROW` formula.

```cpp
=BYROW(A2:F21;LAMBDA(row;SPARKLINE(row;{"charttype"\"column";"color"\"green";"ymin"\MIN(row);"ymax"\MAX(row)*1,2})))
```

Comment: nothing simpler, very good, thks